# AWS: Convert t1.micro (PV) to t2.medium (HVM)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have t1.micro (PV) and I am trying to update (resize) to t2.medium (HVM).

However, when I created AMI from t1.micro and tried to attach to t2.medium, I did not get instance under list. So could not attached AMI to t2.medium.

So may I know how can I attached AMI to new instance from EC2 Console? Also, how can I take care of SSH , SSL , Cron , multi domains while migrating?

Resource I refereed: http://www.nixhat.com/2014/01/migrate-aws-pv-to-hvm-instance/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the directions on that page. Let me highlight part of it.

1. Launch any HVM based centos.
2. Create a volume snapshot from your PV based instance
3. Attach the snapshot to the HVM
4. **Copy kernel and other boot files from HVM to PV snapshot volume**
5. Stop the instance
6. Detach root disk from HVM
7. Attach the PV snapshot to the instance as root device
8. Launch the instance

Note you are not attempting to launch your PV instance on a t2 machine, you are launching a new HVM instance. You are responsible to find and copy any configuration that you've changed, such as crons and configuration.

Note this question goes against the principle of "[treat your servers like cattle, not pets](http://www.networkworld.com/article/2165267/cloud-computing/why-servers-should-be-seen-like-cows--not-puppies.html)". It appears you don't have a way to recreate your server/configuration from scratch, which should be a red flag- instances go down, people accidentally break their configuration, and so on.

Comment: not sure why it get negs. Anyway, I tried to copy kernel and boot files from AWS console but could not find any option. Is SSH only way to copy files?

Comment: Note step 3- you are attaching the snapshot to your new instance. it's just a local copy.